# How to filter search input to show correct autocomplete in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search input where my autocomplete shows but for some reason it the results are not being filtered - can anyone tell or show me a way to filter results to show the correct autocomplete prior in my code below.. Below is the json format and the html code updated. Thanks for the help.

**Here is my code**

```
       $( function() {
    var cache = {};
    $( "#searchTextField" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
          response( cache[ term ] );
          return;
        }

        $.post( "http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", request, 
        function( data, status, xhr ) {
          cache[ term ] = data;
          response( data );
        });
      }
    });
  } );
```

**JobSearchItem Return JSON**

```
[
   {
    "id": "9000",
    "label": "PROGRAMMER TEST 1 (9000) ",
    "value": "90000"
},
 ]
```

**html**

```
 <h:body>
<f:view transient="true">
  <tp:header/>
  <tp:searchForm/>



  <div id="results">

  </div>

 <h:panelGroup  id="dTable" class="container">
        </h:panelGroup>


</f:view>
   <f:view transient="true">
<div class="jobEntity">
  <div class="job-container-header">
    <h4>#{testBean.jobEntity.toString()}</h4>

    <c:if test="#{testBean.jobEntity.validURLConnection}">
      <a href="#{testBean.jobEntity.pGradeDescriptionLink}" 
         class="btn btn-info-One"   
         target="_blank">[ Test ]</a>
    </c:if>

    <h4>#{testBean.jobEntity.mu} - #{testBean.jobEntity.muDescription}</h4>
    <h4>#{testBean.jobEntity.specialNotes}</h4> 
    <h4>#{testBean.jobEntity.syRgeMnSepMsg}</h4>
  </div>

  <c:if test="${testBean.jobEntity.sectionToDisplay eq 'Range'}">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <c:forEach var="stepNumber" begin="1" end="#{testBean.jobEntity.stepSize}">
            <th>Step #{stepNumber}</th>
          </c:forEach>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="#{testBean.jobEntity.jobRows}" var="jobRow">
          <tr>
            <th>#{jobRow.rateType}</th>
            <c:forEach items="#{jobRow.steps}" var="step">
              <td>#{step.amount}</td>
            </c:forEach>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </c:if>
</div>
```

Comment: In your HTML, where is the `<input>` with ID: `searchTextField`?

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the content of `JobSearchItem.xhtml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling data from a .xhtml file, it is not going to be able to filter the results, unless you can update the server side script to accept and perform activities based on data posted to it.

I would suggest you gather the static data upfront and then filter based on that. This might look something like:

```
$( function() {
  var myData;
  $.get( "http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function( data ){
    myData = data;
  } );
  $( "#searchTextField" ).autocomplete( {
    minLength: 2,
    source: myData
  } );
} );
```

This assumes that your xhtml is providing a Array of data (usually in JSON format). This can be simple:

```
[
  "Item 1",
  "Item 2",
  "Item 3"
];
```

Or something more advanced:

```
[{
  "label": "Item 1",
  "value": 1
},{
  "label": "Item 2",
  "value": 2
},{
  "label": "Item 3",
  "value": 3
}];
```

If the data you get back is something else: HTML Table, XML, or text, then using a function with Source will help you. If you update your question and provide an example of the data, we could provide a more complete example or guidance.

**Update 1**

Given the following JSON Data:

```
[{
  "id": "9000",
  "pGrade": "0",
  "label": "PROGRAMMER TEST 1"
},{
  "id": "6000",
  "pGrade": "0",
  "label": "WEB PROGRAMMER TEST 1"
}];
```

This does not comply with the standard Autocomplete expected data. If you are able to POST data to `JobSearchItem.xhtml`, then you can have it filter first and return data. If `JobSearchItem.xhtml` does not accept POST, then I would perform a GET of all the data up front and then filter it later. I will include an example of both.

**POST**

If you are posting the data, the server-side script needs to know what data you are sending it in the form of a variable name and value. You did not supply a variable name in your example and you have not supplied the `JobSearchItem.xhtml` content, so it's really hard to identify how this script works.

For this example, we will use `term` and our example data will be `we`. If this was a GET command, it would look like:

```
JobSearchItem.xhtml?term=we
```

For Post we will use an Object that is submitted:

```
{ "term": "we" };
```

Here are the basics:

```
$(function(){
  var cache = {};
  $("#searchTextField").autocomplete( {
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response){
      var t = request.term;
      if (t in cache){
          response(cache[t]);
          return;
      }
      var results = [];
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml",
        data: {
          term: t
        },
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
          $.each(data, function(k, v){
            results.push({
              label: v.label,
              value: v.label,
              id: v.id,
              grade: v.pGrade
            });
          });
          cache[t] = results;
        });
        response(results);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

So, in this case, if the user enters `we`, this is sent to the script, which will filter the results and will send back JSON that should look like:

```
[{
  "id": "6000",
  "pGrade": "0",
  "label": "WEB PROGRAMMER TEST 1"
}];
```

Since Autocomplete is expecting an object containing `label` and `value` can't just be sent direct to `response()`. Using `$.each()` we can iterate the results and adjust so that it's formatted for Autocomplete.

**GET**

If your `obSearchItem.xhtml` is static and just provides a list of JSON data, using GET might be a good way to collect this data. Consider that you can get all this data up front, and then use it later. This is the most common way to use Autocomplete, but the data still has to be in the right format.

```
$( function() {
  var myData = [];
  $.get("http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      myData.push({
        label: v.label,
        value: v.label,
        id: v.id,
        grade: v.pGrade
      });
    });
  });
  $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: myData
  });
});
```

One of these should work.

Comment: So, the code that you provide, does not even show the autocomplete. But the code in my question does show the autocomplete.

Comment: My example shows autocomplete using data that is already collected from the server.

Comment: There are many ways. Can use GET or POST and have a script return the data in different formats. If you update your post and provide a more complete example, can provide a better answer.

Comment: But, that is the only JQuery Script I have for this problem.

Comment: What about the html? Also provide what is returned by your JobSearchItem.xhtml

Comment: @Vee I updated the answer to reflect the new details you provided. There are still some questions, which I commented on before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182949/discussion-between-vee-and-twisty).

Comment: I tried both POST and GET .. But it is not working anymore. Please click on the continue the discussion to chat

Comment: also, I updated my json results. Please have a look,

Comment: @Vee Ok, how did you "update" your JSON results? If the results now include  `label` and `value`, you could just send the results as `source`. It might be best to post the content of `JobSearchItem.xhtml` since nothing is adding up from what you have posted or provided.

Comment: let's chat here at stackoverflow - just click on the  discussion in chat button I sent you

Comment: the get request one

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a remote URL as the datasource like this, the remote server is expected to do the filtering based on the search term given to it by the autocomplete, and return the results already filtered.

Autocomplete only carries out the filtering if you provide it with static data. See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for more details.

N.B. If your remote server is unable to do any filtering (e.g. because it just returns a static file) then you'd have to filter the data client-side in your callback before you return it to the autocomplete. But of course this is not very efficient because you keep downloading all the data and then discarding most of it (unless the browser helpfully caches it).

Comment: I think remote server is not doing any filtering. Can you show some code how to do it in client side call-back?

Comment: it would be better to do it in the server, if you can. Try that first. But even if not, really I don't think you need me to show you how to check whether a string matches any part of another string using JS? You can google that 1000 times over.

Comment: can I do it with google json library called GSON? Cause I am rendering my json via java like that

Comment: perhaps, I don't know that library at all. I'm not a Java developer, sorry. Check the docs for the library, or google for previous examples, or ask a separate question tagged with Java where you show your current server code. I imagine you would filter the data _before_ you turn it into JSON, though. JSON is just for transmitting the data. e.g. If you get the data from some database, then it's likely to be better to filter it via a SQL query rather than trying to filter the JSON.

Comment: No problem. Meanwhile if the answer has helped you to understand why the filtering is not occurring then please don't forget to mark as accepted - thanks :-)